# How to loop through a pandas dataframe to run an independent ttest for each of the variables?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, t-test

I have a dataset that consists of around 33 variables. The dataset contains patient information and the outcome of interest is binary in nature. Below is a snippet of the data.

The dataset is stored as a pandas dataframe

```
df.head()
```

```
ID     Age  GAD  PHQ  Outcome
1      23   17   23      1
2      54   19   21      1
3      61   23   19      0
4      63   16   13      1
5      37   14   8       0
```

I want to run independent t-tests looking at the differences in patient information based on outcome. So, if I were to run a t-test for each alone, I would do:

```
age_neg_outcome = df.loc[df.outcome ==0, ['Age']]
age_pos_outcome = df.loc[df.outcome ==1, ['Age']]

t_age, p_age = stats.ttest_ind(age_neg_outcome ,age_pos_outcome, unequal = True)

print('\t Age: t= ', t_age, 'with p-value= ', p_age)
```

How can I do this in a for loop for each of the variables?

I've seen this post which is slightly similar but couldn't manage to use it.

[Python : T test ind looping over columns of df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002342/python-t-test-ind-looping-over-columns-of-df)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. `ttest_ind` accepts multi-dimensional arrays too:

```py
cols = ['Age', 'GAD', 'PHQ']
cond = df['outcome'] == 0

neg_outcome = df.loc[cond, cols]
pos_outcome = df.loc[~cond, cols]

# The unequal parameter is invalid so I'm leaving it out
t, p = stats.ttest_ind(neg_outcome, pos_outcome)
for i, col in enumerate(cols):
    print(f'\t{col}: t = {t[i]:.5f}, with p-value = {p[i]:.5f}')
```

Output:

```
    Age: t = 0.12950, with p-value = 0.90515
    GAD: t = 0.32937, with p-value = 0.76353
    PHQ: t = -0.96683, with p-value = 0.40495
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply on this. This works perfectly. I have encountered another issue though where when there are too many NANs in a variable the output comes out as t = nan, p = nan. I managed to find a solution to it on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022888/t-test-in-scipy-with-nan-values, where they resolved the issue by dropping the nans before passing them to the t-test. Any suggestions on how to implement this in this loop?